# Regex match order

Tags: c#, regex

From this possible input i want to mach the bold text:

> Genre: **Thriller, Adventure, Action**, 2012
>
> Genre: **Thriller, Adventure, Action**

I did something like this `(?<=Genre: ).*(?=(, \d{4})?)`

My problem is that I put this part `(, \d{4})?` hoping that because there is match `", 2012"` it would stop at this point but it not, its just ignore the matching...

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, so it will consume anything it can. Since the last part with the digits is optional, it all gets consumed by the `.*`.

There may be a more eloquent way of doing it, but maybe just have two regexes:

```
(?<=Genre: ).*(?=(, \d{4}))|(?<=Genre: ).*
```

If I'm right the first will match in the case with the numbers, but it will fall through to the more general case if that fails.

**Edit:** Actually, it might work to do something like the following:

```
(?<=Genre: ).*?(?=(, \d{4})|$)
```

That way the `.*` is not greedy, but it *must* consume everything up to either the digits or else the end of the string.

Comment: This works great thank you.. If there is any way to do it with one regex I would like to learn it